# Unity Assets doesn't collision with player, but cubes etc. does

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to test making games with Unity the first time but I don't get, why the player only collides with normal elements like cubes, planes etc. (so elements, which you can create in unity), but with assets like a floor or something it doesn't work. The player just goes through the asset objects. I'm sure I have to change something at the asset objects, but what?

Comment: never mind. I found it. I had to add "mesh collider" to the object

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a suitable type of `Collider` ([ref](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.html)), the default Unity `GameObject`s come with Colliders preattached.

Answer (score 0):

You should add **Collider Component** to the object.
[Check this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bh9ArKrPY8w)